# Matched fragment when using Lucene's RegexQuery

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I'm performing query operations on a Lucene index with a RegexQuery. For example, I do a RegexQuery to obtain all documents containing a URL, using `new RegexQuery(new Term("text", "https?://[^\\s]+")` (I know, the RegEx is over-simplified).

Now I want to retrieve the text fragment, which actually matched my query, like `http://example.com`. Does Lucene offer an efficient possibility therefore? Or do I have process the whole text again, using Java's RegEx matcher?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the thing you exactly want is impossible, but here is a different approach that has a similar effect:

Open an Indexreader, get all terms which are after "http" (ordered by lexicographical order[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)) until they don't start with "http://" or "https://" anymore:

```
    final IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(IndexHelper.DIRECTORY, true);
    final TermEnum termEnum = reader.terms(new Term("text", "http"));
    final List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<Term>();
    Term foundTerm = termEnum.term();

    // if the first term does not match url pattern: advance until it first matches
    if (!(foundTerm.text().startsWith("https://") || foundTerm.text().startsWith("http://"))) {
        while (termEnum.next()) {
            foundTerm = termEnum.term();
            if (foundTerm.text().startsWith("https://") || foundTerm.text().startsWith("http://")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // collect all terms
    while ((foundTerm.text().startsWith("https://") || foundTerm.text().startsWith("http://")) && termEnum.next()) {
        foundTerm = termEnum.term();
        terms.add(foundTerm);
    }
```

The resulting urls are then in the "terms" list, as lucene Terms.

This of course has the disadvantage that you don't get the documents in which these URLs were found, but you can query them afterwards again with the found terms.

The way I layed it out here is not very flexible (but possibly faster for the task to achieve), but you can of course go back to patterns to achieve more flexibility. Then you would replace all `foundTerm.text().startsWith("https://") || foundTerm.text().startsWith("http://")` with `yourPattern.matches(foundTerm.text())`.

And sorry that I wrote so much ^^.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and sorry for my late response, Enduriel. Unfortunately, my example might have been a bit too trivial, as there are not only URLs for which I have to query, but also more sophisticated patterns, therefore I can not use the prefix solution, but I definitely have to go with the RegexQuery.

Comment: Hi qqilihq, and sorry for my late answer to your response as well. Well, I suppose then my prefix approach won't help in any way. I only used it once for autocompletion (which worked good), but never for anything more sophisticated. So I don't know anything better, but I hope you will find a good solution.